# Adding an Image with PDFKit

Tags: javascript, browserify, pdfkit

I've tried adding a local image to a PDF file generated using PDFKit like so:

```
doc.image("images/notToBeUsedForBusinessSolicitations.png", 0, 0, 300);
```

However, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined

So I then tried to convert the local image to an `arraybuffer` then use that to set the image like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onload = function() {
    doc.image(xhr.response, 0, 0, 300);
};
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.open('GET','images/notToBeUsedForBusinessSolicitations.png', true);
xhr.send();
```

But then I get this error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

What do I need to do to get this image into my PDF?